# Error when starting Docker daemon with user other than root (permission denied)

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, debian, daemon

I want to start the Docker daemon with a user other than root.

I'm trying to start it with `docker daemon --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --storage-driver=vfs`.

Sadly this error occurs:

> FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: open /var/run/docker.pid: permission
>   denied

When I look into the directory `/var/run/` I can't see any file named 
`docker.pid`.

Starting the service as `root` works without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker daemon must run as root.

Edit: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#/docker-daemon-attack-surface